# Not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, build

I'm having an issue with this piece of Java code. When trying to build the program to which this code belongs too, I get back this error :

```
        [javac] C:\eRA\cc284-src\reporting\jsp\test\net\sourceforge\cruisecontrol\mock\MockServletRequest.java:59: error: MockServletRequest is not abstract and does not override abstract method <T>upgrade(Class<T>) in HttpServletRequest
```

Here is my code:

```
  package net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.mock;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
  import java.security.Principal;
  import java.util.Enumeration;
  import java.util.Locale;
  import java.util.Map;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Collections;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
  import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
  import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class MockServletRequest implements HttpServletRequest {
private String contextPath = "";
private String servletPath;
private Map params = new HashMap();
private String pathInfo;
private Locale locale;


public void httpservletrequest() {
}


public MockServletRequest() {
}

public MockServletRequest(String contextPath, String servletPath) {
    this.contextPath = contextPath;
    this.servletPath = servletPath;
}

public Object getAttribute(String name) {
    return null;
}

public Enumeration getAttributeNames() {
    return null;
}

public String getCharacterEncoding() {
    return null;
}

public int getContentLength() {
    return 0;
}

public String getContentType() {
    return null;
}

public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    return null;
}

public String getParameter(String paramName) {
    ArrayList values = (ArrayList) params.get(paramName);
    if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
        return null;    // param not found
    }
    return (String) values.get(0);
}

public Enumeration getParameterNames() {
    return Collections.enumeration(params.keySet());
}

public String[] getParameterValues(String paramName) {
    ArrayList values = (ArrayList) params.get(paramName);
    if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
        return null;    // param not found
    }
    return (String[]) values.toArray(new String[] {});
}

public String getProtocol() {
    return null;
}

public String getScheme() {
    return null;
}

public String getServerName() {
    return null;
}

public int getServerPort() {
    return 0;
}

public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    return null;
}

public String getRemoteAddr() {
    return null;
}

public String getRemoteHost() {
    return null;
}

public void setAttribute(String s, Object o) {
}

public void removeAttribute(String s) {
}

public Locale getLocale() {
    return locale;
}

public Enumeration getLocales() {
    return null;
}

public boolean isSecure() {
    return false;
}

public RequestDispatcher getRequestDispatcher(String s) {
    return null;
}

public String getRealPath(String s) {
    return null;
}

public String getAuthType() {
    return null;
}

public Cookie[] getCookies() {
    return new Cookie[0];
}

public long getDateHeader(String s) {
    return 0;
}

public String getHeader(String s) {
    return null;
}

public Enumeration getHeaders(String s) {
    return null;
}

public Enumeration getHeaderNames() {
    return null;
}

public int getIntHeader(String s) {
    return 0;
}

public String getMethod() {
    return null;
}

public String getPathInfo() {
    return pathInfo;
}

public String getPathTranslated() {
    return null;
}

public String getContextPath() {
    return (contextPath.length() == 0 ? "" : "/" + contextPath);
}

public String getQueryString() {
    return null;
}

public String getRemoteUser() {
    return null;
}

public boolean isUserInRole(String s) {
    return false;
}

public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
    return null;
}

public String getRequestedSessionId() {
    return null;
}

public String getRequestURI() {
    return null;
}

public String getServletPath() {
    return "/" + servletPath;
}

public HttpSession getSession(boolean b) {
    return null;
}

public HttpSession getSession() {
    return null;
}

public boolean isRequestedSessionIdValid() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isRequestedSessionIdFromURL() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isRequestedSessionIdFromUrl() {
    return false;
}

public void addParameter(String paramName, String paramValue) {
    ArrayList values = (ArrayList) params.get(paramName);
    if (values == null) {
        values = new ArrayList();
        params.put(paramName, values);
    }
    values.add(paramValue);
}

public ArrayList removeParameter(String paramName) {
    ArrayList values = (ArrayList) params.remove(paramName);
    return values;
}

public void setPathInfo(String info) {
    pathInfo = info;
}

/**
 * @param locale
 */
public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    this.locale = locale;
}

public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
    return null;
}

public String getLocalAddr() {
    return null;
}

public String getLocalName() {
    return null;
}

public int getLocalPort() {
    return 0;
}

public Map getParameterMap() {
    return null;
}

public int getRemotePort() {
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to declare it as abstract, I get another error saying it cannot implement.

Comment: What do you think that error message is telling you?

Comment: If you don't want to fix the code, try a different version of tomcat in your deployment. Using tomcat 7 instead of 8 resolved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Deconstruct the error message

```
MockServletRequest is not abstract and does not override abstract method <T>upgrade(Class<T>) in HttpServletRequest
```

and it will tell you the following:

HttpServletRequest has the abstract method "upgrade(Class)". Since you are implementing that class, you need to implement that method.

What the error message is also telling you is that you can also call the **class** MockServletRequest abstract (**not** the  update method). This will pass the implementation requirement to a higher object (but looking at the code this is probably not what you want).

The compiler is complaining because you have done neither of those things.

Answer (score 0):

The HttpServletRequest class has an upgrade(Class) method that must be overridden/implemented when you implement the HttpServletRequest class.
You need to have a method that looks like:

```
public <T extends HttpUpgradeHandler> T upgrade(Class<T> handlerClass) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If `MockServletRequest` is going to override that abstract method (as the compiler will require), make sure you're not declaring `MockServletRequest.update()` as abstract.  That is, declare it as `public void update()`, not `public abstract void update()`.